# What's wrong with my SQL syntax in mariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE 'my testTBL' (id INT);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnpar.png)

I am currently studying mariadb. I am writing and writing simple SQL statements. I use it as it appears in the book, but book's based on version 3, but it doesn't seem to work at 4. How should I change it? What is the problem?

Comment: I very much doubt that spaces in table names are allowed.

Comment: Best solution is to NOT to use spaces in any table name or column names

Comment: You should familiarise yourself with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for composite object name use backtics  not single quote

```
CREATE TABLE `my testTBL` (
  id INT
);
```

see this doc for naming convention  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Why is the table name in the single quotes and contain spaces? 
Remove these and it will work. 
If at all, you wish to put the table/column names in quotes, use backticks (the quote below the `esc` key) instead of singlequotes (`'`).
Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c5b4f/1) for this.